# Passing inherited structs to poll()

Tags: c++, inheritance, system-calls, polling

```
class Socket{ //implementation
};

struct PollSocket : pollfd  {
     Socket mSocket;
     // some methods
}

std::vector<PollSocket> mPolledSockets;
poll(mPolledSockets.data(), mPolledSockets.size(), 0);
```

Can I pass inherited structs to poll()? If not, why? It seems I get a lot of bugs in such case.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Be sure to show all declarations that are needed to compile your code example.

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: You can pass one, but not an array of them. An array of `PollSocket` is not an array of `pollfd`.

Comment: You should look at how poll() works : [poll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). The layouts of memory are not the same (pollfd[] vs PollSocket[] ), so that your program works with 1 PollSocket but bugs if 2 or more.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the question is pretty clear the way it is, I'd disagree with the need for more code. I am also uncertain why the question was downvoted.

Comment: @SergeyA Specifically, I was wondering about the signature for `poll()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this is a Posix function, so it's signature is well-known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't treat an array (or vector) of objects polymorphically, and this question is not specific to `poll` mechanism.

The reason is rather simple - if the function expects a pointer to N objects, each of which has size Z, and you pass it an array of N objects each of which has size Z1, the function will be very confused - it would expect the second object to begin at offset Z, while instead it would begin at offset Z1. Of course, it will lead to all sort of troubles.

The situation would be different, if function expected the array of **pointers** to objects - this would work.